# Angular keep selection between controllers and support routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, state

I have a `LIST` view that shows a set of items. In this view the user can select the items.

Then I have a `DETAILS` view that shows the details about the selected items.

The application moves from `LIST` view to `DETAILS` view changing the location. The selected items are passed as URL parameters (for example /cars/ids=1,2,3).

Putting the ids in the URL lets the user bookmark the URL of `DETAILS` view and see the elements when he opens the bookmarked URL again.

The `DETAILS` view has a back button that lets the user go back to the `LIST` view. When the user go back to the `LIST` view I want that previous selected elements are shown as selected.

How to pass back the selected items from `DETAILS` to `LIST`?

I see two solution:

1. Keep the selection state in a service. When the application is open using the `DETAILS` view URL, the controller set the selected items in the service taking them from the URL.
2. Using the same mechanism used for moving from `LIST` to `DETAILS`: put the selected items in the URL as parameter. Then the `LIST` controller retrieve it from the URL.

Which solution is better?

Answer (score 1):

First off I think both of your solutions might work.

1) is sensitive to the user doing a page reload

2) it's good generally but beware if the amount of data grow in the url

Ultimately it's a matter of taste more..

Do you want the user to bookmark a listpage with selected ids? If not then I would like to introduce a third possible solution

```
var parameters = [ id1, id2, id3 ];

// set in detail view
localStorage.setItem('params',JSON.stringify(parameters)); 

// to retrieve in list view
var selectedParameters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('params'))
```

This way you don't have to worry that the user does refresh on page..

Best of luck..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not worried about page refresh, but sometimes the user wants to pass the URL to other users, so I can't keep the state on the local browser.

Comment: Then 2 definitely feels like the way to go. With that I mean that your selected items are query params